# How to set from mail address other than smtp authentication mail in java mail

Tags: email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am specifying "FROM" address usinf setFrom() method, But i still receive mails having "FROM" address of SMTP authentication mail id. and want to **set the "FROM" address dynamically**.  which keeps changing. What is the RFC282 standard to achieve this.

Comment: this might help https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution from google is this

**Gmail lets you send messages with another of your email addresses listed as the sender instead of your Gmail address. This feature helps you manage multiple accounts from the Gmail interface; it works only if you already own the email account linked to the alternate address**

1. Select the Accounts and Import tab (or Accounts tab, if you're using Google Apps).
   Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.
   In the 'Email address' field, enter your name and alternate email address.
   Choose one of two options:
   Use Gmail's servers to send your mail (this is easier to set up)
   Use your other email provider's SMTP servers (we recommend this option for professional mail accounts or domains). Note for Google Apps users: Depending on your domain2 type, this feature may be disabled by default. Talk to your administrator if you have any questions.
   If you choose to use Gmail's servers:
2. Click Next Step >> and then click Send Verification. Gmail will send a verification message to your other email address to confirm that you own it.
3. Open your other account and either click the link in the message Gmail sent or enter the confirmation code in the Accounts section of your Gmail settings.

For more info, follow the below link

https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370.

**The overhead involved is that any new from address needs a alias to be set in Gamil authentication mail account. Its not suits for enterprise salable app.**

Other solution is You can install a mail server (hmailServer). This server allows you to set the custom from address

If any body knows other solutions, please suggest me.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Comment: Links to Gmail's blog rot more slowly than its help pages, I reckon: http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html

Answer (score 4):

It's up to your mail server.  Often mail servers will prevent you from using any From address other than your actual login name.  This helps prevent spam.  Depending on your mail server, there may be ways to convince it that you should be allowed to use other From addresses.

Answer (score 2):

These are two different things that you are talking about:

> The id that you are mentioning is part of smtp handshaking protocol which usually is mapped to "Return-path" field in mime-header.
>
> Whereas the id that comes in "FROM" field which actually is displayed in mail-list is been appended by the mail server when u compose the mail.

So if you can modify the mime header then make sure that "FROM:" field contains the id that yuou want to set not the smtp authentication id.

btw its rfc822

Have worked for rediffmail technical team in order to develop and enhance smtp, pop and imap protocols

Answer (score 2):

Its depends on your mail server and configuration setting